# Ansible search and replace without regex only string literals to avoid escaping

Tags: string, search, replace, ansible

i like to search and replace string which makes me to escape allot of if i use the regexp search / replace  :

in the mystuff.txt (soory about the blah blah but is allot of personal text ) i have allot of string but i like to search and replace those:

```
Blah Blah ${DBNname.db_name} Blah Blah 
Blah Blah ${DBNname.db_name} Blah Blah 
Blah Blah ${DBName.ip}
```

In ansible playbook i have this :

```
- name: search 
  replace:
    path: "foo/mystuff.txt"
    regexp: "{{ item.split('|')[0] }}"
    replace: "{{ item.split('|')[1] }}"
  with_items: "{{ config_list }}"
```

And in command line i passing :

```
config_list =['\\\${DBNname\\\.db_name}|MySql','\\\${DBName\\\.ip}|127.0.0.1']
```

and this is working fine .

As you can see i have allot of escaping going on i like to avoid it as the paramters can be long.

Comment: its as minimal as i can post here as it is private large project , edited the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you required to pass in your `config_list` variable on the command line? Because if you put it in a file instead, the escaping is much simpler. For example, if I place the following content in `config_list.yml`:

```
config_list:
  - search: '\${DBNname\.db_name}'
    replace: 'MySql'
  - search: '\${DBNname\.ip}'
    replace: '127.0.0.1'
```

I can run this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: mystuff.txt
        regexp: '{{ item.search }}'
        replace: '{{ item.replace }}'
      loop: '{{ config_list }}'
```

Like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @config_list.yml
```

And it transforms this:

```
${DBNname.db_name}
${DBNname.ip}
```

Into:

```
MySql
127.0.0.1
```

---

If you really need to pass parameters on the command line using the format shown in your question, this seems
to work:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e '{"config_list": ["\\${DBNname\\.db_name}|MySql", "\\${DBNname\\.ip}|127.0.0.1"]}'
```

If you write the playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: mystuff.txt
        regexp: '{{ x.0 }}'
        replace: '{{ x.1 }}'
      vars:
        x: "{{ item.split('|') }}"
      loop: '{{ config_list }}'
```

The above playbook also works with this input:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e 'config_list="[\"\\${DBNname\\.db_name}|MySql\", \"\\${DBNname\\.ip}|127.0.0.1\"]"'
```

Comment: i can't use file ,the parameters are created dynamically ....

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional options.